# How can I use "fill series" without appearance of unwanted commas?

Tags: google-sheets

before:

```
V 2013
```

I am using fill series to fill cells below.

expected:

```
V 2013
V 2013
V 2013
```

result:

```
V 2013
V 2,013
V 2,013
```

I found only http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/kv1kDdzoYOY - without any useful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the keyboard shortcut for Fill Down: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Make sure to highlight the range you want to fill beforehand. You can either use <kbd>shift</kbd>+click with the mouse, or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> with keyboard to highlight the range.

This seems like a bug in Google Spreadsheets. I was able to replicate when using mouse to drag the bottom right corner, but <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> works fine.